# how to determine the reason a process is crashing

Tags: linux, debugging, crash

I've got an icinga2 process running on Linux which, once or twice a day (at unpredictable times) simply disappears and is no longer running. I'm running the process with its `-x debug` option, but this does not provide any useful information. The log file shows normal operation, and then suddenly there are no more entries in the log and the process is no longer running.

How can I gather more information about why this process is disappearing/crashing?

Comment: Read about core dumps if you suspect it really "crashes". You have to raise the limit to allow core dumps to be generated. And you need a usable development environment to dive into the source code with the information collected in that core dump file.

Comment: i don't know if it's really "crashing." It just disappears. I've analyzed core dumps before with gdb, but I don't do it regularly, my skills with that are minimal. Is there something else I could try first?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to run strace so that it will watch for an exit event?

Comment: I'm running the following, I don't know if it will give me anything interesting: `strace -p 3435 -e signal -e trace=process -e trace=signal -t -o /tmp/strace.icinga &`